# How to Split a String without deleting split character

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, substring

I would like to split a `String` into parts, but when the String is split the character shouldn't be deleted.

In my Example, I would like to have the Output:

```
parts[0]= 4x
parts[1]= -3y
parts[2]= 6z
parts[3]= 3v
```

This is my Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Polynomaddition {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fraction = "4x-3y+6z+3v";
    String [] parts = fraction.split("(?<=\\[a-z]");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
    //String result = calculator(fraction);
}

public static String calculator(String s) {
    String result = "";
     String [] parts = s.split("(?<=[a-z])", -1);

    return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"(?<=[a-z])"` without that -1 is fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

In your cases, it seems you want this regex `\+|(?=-)` :

```
String[] parts = fraction.split("\\+|(?=-)");
```

details

- split with
- `\+` plus sign
- `|` or
- `(?=-)` minus without deleting it

---

### Solution 2

Or with your regex but you need to check each result, for example :

```
String[] parts = Arrays.stream(fraction.split("(?<=[a-z])"))
        .map(s -> s.startsWith("+") ? s.substring(1, s.length()) : s)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

**Outputs**

```
[4x, -3y, 6z, 3v]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `split` at all.  Instead, use a pattern that matches the actual polynomial term, and use a Matcher, specifically its [find](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) and [group](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) methods, to extract each matched term:

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();

Matcher termMatcher = Pattern.compile("[-+]?\\d+[a-z]").matcher(fraction);
while (termMatcher.find()) {
    String part = termMatcher.group();
    if (part.startsWith("+")) {
        part = part.substring(1);
    }
    parts.add(part);
}

System.out.println(parts);
```